# Can I write server, client code in a same program and run them

Tags: c, sockets

just trying to test socket programming. I am thinking to create a project and write both server.c and client.c in that same project. Is it possible or do I have to create two projects and run them parallely? I am writing in C.

Comment: Yes, you can. It is probably simpler to write them different from the start (e.g. no need to deal with spawning multiple processes or threading), but it's possible to do this. Or, perhaps, just use a command-line argument to run the client *or* server part of the program ..

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. I will do separate for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. but if you're using an IDE (eclipse, or something else you prefer) it would be easier for you to do it in separate projects, as you can just build & run each one and both projects will run in parallel, and then the server & client will be able to communicate with each other.

When they are in the same project, you can tell the IDE to build the project, but you'll have to run it from command-line in order to run server & client at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. I will do separate for now.

Comment: Hi but my requirement asks me to do it by command-line model. So I guess I should give the client ip address as argument. Am I correct?

Comment: Maybe, but I guess you're doing some exercise and therefore have some requirements to follow.